# Possible to reduce duplicate code in near-identical javascript functions in different HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, html

I want a user to input their top ten favourite movies, each in a separate text input field. As they type in a box, a 'onkeyup' event triggers a JS function, which makes what they are typing reappear directly below where they are typing.

Do I have to write out ten different JS onkeyup functions for each box, or is there a relatively straightforward way that a single function can do the job, via the means of variables or somesuch?

Maybe this make things clearer:

HTML

```
<form id="movie1">
<h3>Your favourite movie</h3><br><br>
Type the name of your favourite movie: <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="50" onkeyup="inputMovieOne()">
<p>Your favourite movie:<span id=movie1goeshere></span><span></p>
</form>

<form id="movie2">
<h3>Your second favourite movie</h3><br><br>
Type the name of your second favourite movie: <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="50" onkeyup="inputMovieTwo()">
<p>Your second favourite movie:<span id=movie2goeshere></span><span></p>
</form>

...and so on eight more times...
```

JS

```
<script>
function inputMovieOne() {

  var x = document.getElementById("movie1").elements.namedItem("name").value;

  document.getElementById("movie1goeshere").innerHTML =  x;
}

function inputMovieTwo() {

  var x = document.getElementById("movie2").elements.namedItem("name").value;

  document.getElementById("movie2goeshere").innerHTML =  x;
}
</script>

...and so on eight more times...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider [avoiding inline handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045) - they have way too many problems to be worth using in a modern codebase. Instead, select the input box and add a `keyup` listener to each using `addEventListener`. On keyup, navigate to the `<span>` on the next element by referencing the `input.nextElementSibling.children[0]`, and change its text:

```js
for (const input of document.querySelectorAll('input')) {
  input.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
    input.nextElementSibling.children[0].textContent = input.value;
  });
}
```

```html
<form >
<h3>Your favourite movie</h3><br><br>
Type the name of your favourite movie: <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="50" >
<p>Your favourite movie:<span ></span><span></p>
</form>

<form >
<h3>Your second favourite movie</h3><br><br>
Type the name of your second favourite movie: <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="50" >
<p>Your second favourite movie:<span ></span><span></p>
</form>
```

Note that unless you're *explicitly inserting* HTML markup, you should not use `innerHTML` - `innerHTML` is slower and more unsafe than assigning to the `textContent` of an element. Best to set `textContent` by default, and only use `innerHTML` when you have HTML markup that you know is safe.

Comment: That works amazingly, thank you! I learned about 4 separate things from your reply (nextElementSibling, children, inline handlers, and .textContent). But a new problem occurred, in the way that all whitespace is reduced to a single space. So for example, lets say the person types '       Dirty     Dancing     ', it will reappear as ' Dirty Dancing '. Do you know, is there a straightforward fix for this, so that all the whitespace reappears?

Comment: Multiple white spaces in HTML get condensed into a single one. I guess if you need to accept multiple whitespaces, you can use a regular expression to replace all spaces in the input value with `&nbsp;` and then set the `.innerHTML` - but since you have to use `innerHTML`, you'll also want to escape tag delimiters and replace `<`s as well.